# Use diff to find difference in the output of two grep command

Tags: bash, terminal, grep, diff

Is it possible to `diff` the output of two `grep` commands?

I am currently searching for files, using different exclude patterns, and the output it pretty long, so i wanted to see if my new pattern worked, or the output is still the same..

Is it possible to somehow pipe two `grep` command into a `diff` or something like that?

```
grep --exclude=*{.dll, pdb} --ril "dql"
grep  --ril "dql"
```

Comment: Redirect the `grep` output into 2 files and then `diff` the files.

Comment: Please, read [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @DavidPostill That was my initial idea, but wanted to know if there was a neater "trick" rather than creating temp files, and `diff` those.

Answer (score 3):

Using [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) *on the fly* :

```
diff <(grep pattern file) <(grep another_pattern file)
```

> Process Substitution: `<(command)` or `>(command)` is replaced by a FIFO or /dev/fd/* entry. Basically shorthand for setting up a named pipe. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessSubstitution.
>   Example: `diff -u <(sort file1) <(sort file2)`

So :

```
diff <(grep --exclude=*{.dll, pdb} --ril "dql") <(grep  --ril "dql")
```

Comment: hmmm... 
I am getting error message 
`diff: extra operand `/dev/fd/61'`

Comment: -bash: 0: ambiguous redirect

Comment: I think you made a typo

Comment: not  sure where though.. 

`diff  <(grep --exclude=*.{dll,pdb,svg,DS_Store,exe,zip,tdf,Oracle,sql,cache,txt,cfs,fnm,log,css,xdt,psm1} -ril "del" .) <(grep --exclude=*.{dll,pdb,svg,DS_Store,exe,zip,tdc,Oracle,sql,cache,txt,cfs,fnm,log,css,xdt,psm1} -ril "del" .)`

Answer (score 1):

In `bash` using [process substitution](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessSubstitution):

```
$ echo a > FILE
$ echo b > FILE1
$ diff <(grep a *) <(grep b *)
1c1
< FILE:a
---
> FILE1:b
```

As describen in `man bash`:

```
   Process Substitution
   Process substitution is supported on systems that support named
   pipes (FIFOs) or the /dev/fd method of naming open files.  It
   takes the form of <(list) or >(list).  The process list is run
   with its input or output connected to a FIFO or some file in
   /dev/fd.  The name of this file is passed as an argument to the
   current command as the result of the expansion.  If the >(list)
   form is used, writing to the file will provide input for list.
   If the <(list) form is used, the file passed as an argument
   should be read to obtain the output of list.

   When available, process substitution is performed
   simultaneously with parameter and variable expansion,
   command substitution, and arithmetic expansion.
```

Comment: the tldp bash guide is outdated, and in some cases just plain wrong.

Comment: It's just the first result that showed up, I've also added an excerpt from `man bash`.

Comment: Please never link tldp. It's not because it's the first from your search that is the most relevant. http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessSubstitution is a quite better place, really

Comment: Could you give an example when `TLDP` is wrong or outdated? I've never really used it to learn but still it could be useful to know.

Comment: Ask greybot `!tldp` on irc `#bash@irc.freenode.org` and the guys behind. If you want good ressources: FAQ: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ | Guide: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide | Ref: http://gnu.org/s/bash/manual | http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/ | http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes | Check your script: http://www.shellcheck.net/