# How do I take the stdout of two commands and pipe them as two args into sort?

Tags: command-line, bash, sorting

I can do the following:

`sort -nbms file1.txt file2.txt`

and it will merge the two already sorted files.

What I wish to do is take the output from two commands (its sorted) and pipe it in as input instead of file1.txt and file2.txt.

Is that possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use diff to find difference in the output of two grep command](https://superuser.com/questions/1310045/use-diff-to-find-difference-in-the-output-of-two-grep-command)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a job for compound statements in shell. Like this:

`{ command1; command2; } | command3`

In bash you might also use the command redirection syntax:

`command3 < <(command1; command2)`

The above are a general examples which work for any command accepting input from stdin. In your case of course you want to place `sort -nbms` as "command3", and you might also use the process substitution syntax in place of each input file:

`sort -nbms <(command1) <(command2)`

This latter can be used with commands that, like sort, accept more than one input file or that don’t accept stdin at all.